# Reload an external controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, controller, routes

How to reload an external controller in angularjs ?

From a template, I want change and reload it :

```
 $location.path("/pageToReload");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want to reload the current page.
You can use the reload method of either the `$route` or the `$window` service. Inject the service in your controller and then create a method `reloadPage` on your `$scope` :

```
$scope.reloadPage = function() {
   $route.reload();
}
```

Or with `$window` :

```
$scope.reloadPage = function() {
   $window.location.reload();
}
```

You can then call those methods from your template with, for instance, this directive :

```
ng-click="reloadPage()"
```